# Send SMS emoticons in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, sms

I'm sorry, but I speak a little English.

I know send SMS in PHP, but I don't know send special letters or emoticons.

Example (special characters): á (I see smartphone: a)

Example (emoticons):  (I see smartphone: ?)

I don't know character encoding.

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you show me the code where you are sending the sms with PHP?

Comment: SMS technology is very old. If you can do that, it probably involves UCS-2. But the exact internals depend entirely on the API of your SMS provider.